# How to restrict special characters in File Dialog's file name in C#?

Tags: c#

My scenario is, need to restrict the selection of file in an `OpenFileDialog`, when there exists any special characters like #,%,+, -.

I can validate the file name after selecting file by the following code.

```
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

if (result == true)
{
   if(dlg.SafeFileName.Contains("#") || dlg.SafeFileName.Contains("+")
   {
     // show error message;
     // Open file dialog again;   
   }
}
```

Is there any way to validate the file name without closing the dialog?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I upvoted because of the clear and interesting question; still, I would like to know more about your scenario that would require you to restrict filenames. (I can think of one reason, namely selection of files in multi-file projects where some required information is encoded into the filename, but a brief outline in one or two sentences of your scenario might make the question even more comprehensible to some other users.)

Comment: is it an `OpenFileDialog`? What kind of `FileDialog`?

Comment: The actual scenario is to upload the selected file in FTP, where we cannot have a file name with these special characters.

Comment: Yes, it is a OpenFileDialog @Hjalmar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont't know what kind of FileDialog you are using but assuming it's an `OpenFileDialog`, here's something you can do.

```
OpenFileDialog dlg;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.FileOk += dlg_FileOk;
}

void dlg_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (dlg.SafeFileName.Contains("#") || dlg.SafeFileName.Contains("+"))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        // show error message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "FileOk" event. When you press "Save" in your SaveFileDialogue, the FileOk event is triggered. You can then stop the closing of the dialogue.

Here is an example:

```
public void CallDialogue()
{
    var sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.FileOk += ValidateName;

    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sfd.FileName);
    }
}


private void ValidateName(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var sfd = sender as SaveFileDialog;
    var file = new FileInfo(sfd.FileName);
    if (file.Name.Contains('#'))
        e.Cancel = true;

    // i did the FileInfo Stuff to quickly extract ONLY the file name, 
    // without the full path. Thats optional of course. Just an example ;-) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for illustration, you can also put the validation inline if you want:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            using (var dialog = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                dialog.FileOk += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    var dlg = (FileDialog) sender;

                    if (dlg.FileName.IndexOfAny("+#%-".ToCharArray()) < 0)
                        return;

                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid character in filename: " + dlg.FileName);
                    args.Cancel = true;
                };

                dialog.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }
}
```